# Nexus 4 Camera preview aspect Ratio always requires 16x9 surfaceview? Why

Tags: android, camera, preview, aspect-ratio, nexus-4

Device Nexus 4
Android ver: 4.2.2

Hoping someone else has found this and can explain how to resolve it....

Nexus 4 supports the following preview sizes: -

```
W:1280 H:720 Ratio: 1.777777
W:800 H:480 Ratio: 1.6666666
W:768 H:432 Ratio: 1.7777778
W:720 H:480 Ratio: 1.5
W:640 H:480 Ratio: 1.3333334
W:576 H:432 Ratio: 1.3333334
W:480 H:320 Ratio: 1.5
W:384 H:288 Ratio: 1.3333334
W:352 H:288 Ratio: 1.2222222
W:320 H:240 Ratio: 1.3333334
W:240 H:160 Ratio: 1.5
W:176 H:144 Ratio: 1.2222222
```

myCamera.setPreviewSize() sets them, and when I call myCamera.getPreviewSize() I get the correct one that I set, BUT.... If I set my surface view to the same size as my camera preview then I get a stretched image. e.g.

```
setPreviewSize(640,480)
getPreviewSize -> I get 640,480
Surface view (640,480) -> Stretched image
```

Only if I set my Surface view to 16x9 (1.77777) do I get a perfect image.

```
Surface view (1280,720) -> Perfect image
```

This is the only device that I have this issue with. Please can someone advise if there is a camera setting I am missing for full screen mode or something that is stopping this from working.

In my long search I found 1 other post which relates also to this issue, but not an answer, just a bit more evidence of my problem
[PictureCallback not called unless using supportedsizes[0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583757/nexus-4-android-camera-takepicture-does-not-callback-to-onpicturetaken)

Thanks

Comment: Dude !! I have the same issue here. Spent two days on this, and I still don't know why it's producing a stretched image

Answer (score 7):

On the Nexus 4, there's an unfortunate issue where the preview aspect ratio and the still picture aspect ratio are tied together, even if you never take a picture. If they don't match, one of the two gets distorted (typically preview, since it is the lower resolution).

If you want to use a 4:3 preview, configure the still picture size to be 4:3 as well, before starting preview. For example, 640x480 preview with a full 8MP picture size (3264 x 2448) on N4 should cause no stretching for preview.

Use [Camera.Parameters.setPictureSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize%28int,%20int%29) to select the picture size; the list of available sizes can be read from [Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes%28%29).

Comment: This seems to be an issue on all nexus models.

Comment: both @Eddy Talvala 's and beni 's suggestions have helped me to fix my problem. Thank you. Also thanks to Iain for asking this question.

Answer (score 3):

This method calculate the best (for me) screen size for each device. But, I have the same problem like you when I tried this code in the Nexus 4. So, my solution is to have a special case in the end of this method which gets the width of the nexus 4 and calculates the best height for this device.

The last case could be used in all devices. You could delete the first part of the method.

```
private void setAspectResolutionCamera(Parameters camParams, int screen_width, int screen_height) {
    boolean chosen_one_resolution = false;

    //Init screen sizes
    width_video = ConstantsCamera.VIDEO_ASPECT_WIDTH;
    height_video = ConstantsCamera.VIDEO_ASPECT_HEIGHT;

    float aspect_ratio = 1f;
    int aspect_width = 6000, aspect_height = 6000;
    List<Size> supported_sizes_list = camParams.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    for (int i = 0; i < supported_sizes_list.size(); i++) {
        Size size = supported_sizes_list.get(i);

        float aspect = (float) size.height / size.width;
        if (ConstantsCamera.VIDEO_ASPECT_RATIO - aspect <= aspect_ratio && (aspect - ConstantsCamera.VIDEO_ASPECT_RATIO >= 0)) {

            if (screen_width - size.height <= aspect_width && size.height - screen_width >= 0) {

                if (screen_height - size.width < aspect_height) {
                    height_video = size.width;
                    width_video = size.height;
                    aspect_ratio = ConstantsCamera.VIDEO_ASPECT_RATIO - (float) size.height / size.width;
                    aspect_width = screen_width - size.height;
                    aspect_height = screen_height - size.width;

                    chosen_one_resolution = true;


                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Special case
    if (width_video != screen_width && !chosen_one_resolution) {
        height_video = screen_width * height_video / width_video;
        width_video = screen_width;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the size of your surfaceview based on the ratio of the camera parameters that you are using.