# CameraBridgeViewBase parameters

Tags: android, opencv, camera, resolution

I am using OpenCV4Android 2.4.9. My app is using camera via CameraBridgeViewBase object. When I take picture - output image is very small - like 800x600 or sth similar. I have Nexus 4 which is capable of higher resolutions.

How can I set parameters to CameraBridgeViewBase object, so the preview size is higher resolution?

Comment: Here it says maximum camera preview size on Nexus 4 is 1280x720 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361643/nexus-4-camera-preview-aspect-ratio-always-requires-16x9-surfaceview-why - is the size you're observing significantly different?

Comment: I am getting 800x480 exacly.